# .addCursorFlag() is not available on Mongoose Typescript

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose, database-cursor

Below is my mongoose model and I read data from db via cursor. My cursor times out after 10 minutes as mentioned in the documentation.

```
const cursor = this.importRecordModel.find().cursor()
```

I am trying to add below to the end of the cursor but either because of typescript or mongoose, It is not on the available functions list.

```
.addCursorFlag('noCursorTimeout', true);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using [@mongoose/types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mongoose/index.d.ts) if not correct me and tell me which types file you're using.

The types file is not 100% updated correctly, as you can see `addCursorFlag` is only available for an aggregation cursor although `mongoose` does have support for `QueryCursor` `addCursorFlag` as seen [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mongoose/index.d.ts).

I recommend you just add `//@ts-ignore` on top of it and move on. if you want to open a `PR` and add missing methods to that library you're also welcome to.

Personally I dumped `mongoose` over a year ago and never looked back. I encourage other people to do the same.

Comment: If you look this thread, I guess it is removed but still in documentation.
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7056

vkarpov15 commented on Oct 10, 2018
Upon closer inspection, it looks like MongoDB doesn't support noCursorTimeout for aggregation cursors so we're going to have to remove this from the docs and deprecate the function.

Comment: 95 percent of the time you want to use SQL. There are some occasions for MongoDB.